# How can I make read and write http requests in godot with gdscript?

Tags: google-sheets-api, godot

I want to use a spreadsheet as my database for a game and when I do a POST HTTPRequest I get an error of authentication because I can't (of course) sign in to google in my game. I want to know how to give my script OAuth 2.0 access to my spreadsheet and API.

Answer (score 1):

Everything you need to do to get an access token for the sheets api is explained here: 
https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2#basicsteps

I guess you already knew that, but here ...
https://docs.godotengine.org/de/latest/tutorials/networking/http_request_class.html

... is an example how to include headers in your http request in godot.

so in Godot you have to obtain an access token as descriped in the basic steps point 2 and save it. Then you are able to send requests to edit your spreadsheet by adding an Authentication header with the obtained access token to them.